# Eclipse 4.3 Constantly building workspaces

Tags: eclipse, maven

So I just upgraded to Eclipse 4.3 on my Ubuntu machine. For the first couple days it seemed to work fine. Now I am working on a Maven project with XML files and simply want to build the xML beans for my XML schemas. When I do a Maven deploy the workspace is constantly building and refreshing and it takes a good minute or two before the process is actually run. It almost feels like Eclipse is twitching.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? In 4.2 I never experienced this, it was pretty quick and would build the workspace in no time and be done.